# Win Server 2008 add new domain

Tags: iis, iis-7, dns, windows-server-2008

I've just taken on a cloud server with Win 2008 Server installed. I've set-up my 2 dns addresses(ns1.topleveldomain.com / ns2.topleveldomain.com) 1 assigned to each of the IP's(75.100.100.100 & 75.100.100.101) I have.

I've also set-up all the relevant subdomains in the DNS manager and IIS(eg mail.toplelveldomain.com) on the same IP as ns1(eg 75.100.100.100).

I need to add additional sites (eg www.2ndwebsite.com) to the server. Ive already added 'www.2ndwebsite.com' in IIS with the IP '75.100.100.101), but don't know what I need to do in terms of creating this in the DNS manager.

Do I need to create a new Forward Lookup Zone?

Any help with this would be seriously appreciated.

Thanks!

P.s. The IP's and domain above are made up examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just needed records added in the DNS using Forward Lookup Zone.